# If and If statement / using { }

Tags: if-statement

I have a simple question . Why the first program don't work and return me 0 but the second where if go into another if works ? It wont go down and check the next if ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()    
{
    int m,n,tmp,i;
    int nnumber=0,numbermin=9999999;
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
    {
        tmp=i;
        while (tmp > 0 && (tmp % 10) % 2 == 0)
        {
            tmp/=10;  
        } 
        if (tmp == 0){ // This don't work i as want from this if to go down 
                       // there and check the next if
                       // i only got 0 at the printf("%d" , numbermin);
            nnumber=i;  
        }
        if(nnumber<numbermin)
        {
            numbermin=nnumber;
        }

    }
    if(nnumber==0)
        printf("NO");
    else
        printf("%d",numbermin);
}
```

And the code that runs good .

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()    
{
    int m,n,tmp,i;
    int nnumber=0,numbermin=9999999;
    scanf("%d %d",&m,&n);
    for(i=m;i<=n;i++)
    {
        tmp=i;
        while (tmp > 0 && (tmp % 10) % 2 == 0)
        {
            tmp/=10;  
        } 
        if (tmp == 0) {
            nnumber=i;
            if(nnumber<numbermin)
            {
                numbermin=nnumber; // But this work perfect i want to know why the first ex didn't work ?
            }
        }

    }
    if(nnumber==0)
        printf("NO");
    else
        printf("%d",numbermin);
}
```

Why only the second one work good but the first don't ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that in the first example, if `tmp` isn't equal to 0, then the second `if` statement can still be evaluated as true while the first does not.

```
if (tmp == 0){
    nnumber=i;  
}
if(nnumber<numbermin)
{
    numbermin=nnumber;
}
```

While in the second example, if `tmp` is equal to 0, then the first `if` statement is evaluated as false and disallows anything within it from affecting the program.

```
if (tmp == 0){
    nnumber=i;
    if(nnumber<numbermin){
       numbermin=nnumber;
    }
}
```

This would explain the difference in results when running these two versions of the code.